# Dynamically display html content without altering its original styling

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe

I am storing a [classic email template](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_emailtemplates.htm&type=5) as HTML in an attribute called **storedMessage**. My target is to preview my [classic email templates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_emailtemplates.htm&type=5) in a Lightning component. I used the following tag to render the stored email in the component:

```
<aura:attribute name="storedEmail" type="String" default="No preview"/>
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.storedEmail}"/>
```

It works fine, and I can preview the email; however, all the HTML content in **aura:unescapedHtml** is inheriting the styling of the Lightning component, so the preview looks weird.

My approach is to display the attributte **storedEmail** in an iframe, but the iframe in Lighting only supports src with an URL and not srcdoc, so I cannot display the content using my attribute **storedEmail**. My wo-worker advised me to create a visualforce page, maybe called emailContainerPage, and pass the HTML. In this way, I can use the iframe with src, something like:

```
<iframe src="{!'/apex/htmlContainerPage?html=' + v.storedEmail}"></iframe>
```

Is this the only solution for my issue or maybe there is another easy way using aura:unescapedHtml or other Lightning feature?

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Web Components don't inherit the style from a parent, so include your html text in a LWC and then place the LWC in the original lightning aura component/application.